# How to groupby by comparing two columns uisng pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Have a df with columns name and exm_date

```
name   roll       exm_date 

tom    242    2019-03-05 11:48:03.166              
mark   244    2018-03-05 11:48:03.166                   

tom    244    2020-03-05 11:48:03.166              
mark   242    2019-03-05 11:48:03.166
```

How to get the min date by comparing name and roll. if roll is different it should be considered as a separate record

expected_output

```
name   roll       exm_date 

tom    242    2019-03-05 11:48:03.166              
mark   244    2018-03-05 11:48:03.166                   
tom    244    2020-03-05 11:48:03.166
```

For comparing one column(name) with date i was using this :

```
df=df.groupby('name')['exm_date'].min().reset_index()
```

tried this :

```
df=df.groupby('name','roll')['exm_date'].min().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing square brackets(`[]`) in `groupby` clause:

Do this:

```
df = df.groupby(['name','roll'])['exm_date'].min().reset_index()
```